# Where can I find literature on the set-theoretic "problems" arising in category theory?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, set-theory

So my commutative algebra course just did a lecture introducing category theory, and as someone who's taken a decent bit of set theory, I'm very uncomfortable with many of the notions defined in lecture. In general, much of it boils down to defining maps, using quantifiers over, and in general just "doing whatever you want" with objects that aren't sets. I have way too many questions to include in one post, so I'd just like to know where I can read on why all of this category-theoretic stuff is well-defined. Even the very first line "Let $C$ be a category from $\textbf{Set}\to\textbf{Set}$" makes me queasy, haha.

I understand that in daily mathematics, the extent to which this matters is debatable, but it still makes me uneasy, and want to know what's *really* going on here.

Comment: Very fair questions, and something I dealt with as well. [This](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/) is a good starting point.

Comment: I think it is meaningful to first think only about locally small categories. At least for me, the operations in category theory seemed intuitively acceptable over these categories.

Comment: George Bergman's *Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions* (preliminary version available as a PDF [from his website](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/3.2.pdf) ) has a fairly readable discussion. It begins in Chapter 7, and then in Section 7.4 gets down into describing "how we can both encompass category theory within set theory, and have category theory include
structures like 'the category of sets'." His solution is to invoke "universes", whose existence is consistent with ZFC.

Comment: You might also be interested in Shulman's [Set Theory for Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.1279.pdf). It outlines a few ways of solving the problems you're worried about, and compares and contrasts them. Shulman is also a very nice expositor, so the paper is quite readable ^_^.

Comment: In your set theory, did you ever look beyond ZFC? There are other solutions to the paradoxes of Frege's set theory than Zermelo's dropping of universal comprehension. In particular, Russell and Whitehead's Principia Mathematica carefully establishes a hierarchy of sets, where higher sets on hierarchy cannot be elements of lower sets. It is impossible in this system to even form the condition $x \notin x$, much less collectivize it. This system is not for the faint of heart (I folded not very far in), but it led to many simpler class systems later.

Comment: We never went beyond ZFC. It went pretty deep, but never beyond that. I will look into this, though!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin No, universes are not necessarily relatively consistent with ZFC. Let ZFC' denote the axioms of ZFC + "there exists a universe". Then ZFC' $\vdash$ "ZFC is consistent", since the universe would be a model of ZFC. If we had ZFC' $\vdash$ "ZFC and ZFC' are relatively consistent", then we would have ZFC' $\vdash$ "ZFC' is consistent", and therefore, ZFC' would be inconsistent by the 2nd incompleteness theorem.

Comment: @MarkSaving: I may be using the terms incorrectly, but where did "ZFC' proves that ZFC and ZFC' are relatively consistent" come from? I meant: if ZFC' is consistent, then ZFC is consistent. And if ZFC is consistent, then ZFC' is  consistent. Is this not accurate? I don't think saying "theories X and Y are relatively consistent" is the same as saying "theory Y proves that theories X and Y are relatively consistent"...